# Apache / PHP has trouble reading files after svn export

Tags: php, apache, svn

I have the weirdest problem that I can't figure out. I've seen it several times now and everytime the problem is completely inexplicable, and the last time I found out it's 'solvable' by restarting apache.

I have a folder where my website is in. When I'm done with an update and it's in Subversion I then continue to update my website. This is done like this:

```
mv www www-backup-xyz
svn export https://my-svn-repo.com/updated-web-folder www
chmod -R 770 www
chown -R [apache-user:group] www
```

Now, if I go to my browser and refresh my website, I'll get a blank page and my error log will be filled with messages like:

```
[Mon Feb 24 08:40:56 2014] [error] [client x.x.x.x] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'MyClass' not found in /path/to/script/script.php on line 46
```

- The line indicated is where I instantiate MyClass for the first time.
- The class has it's own PHP file which is included a few lines above using require_once.
- There's no error from the require once, so the include was successful.
- If I diff the new MyClass.php with the  version in SVN, it is the same.
- If I check the permissions, both the owner and privileges are the same as any other file.

The file it errors on, is different for every time I run the export process. Seemingly random. It also errors on files that haven't changed since the last update.

If I run an apache2 restart, everything works fine again. So even though, the fix is rather simple, I would like to understand what is happening. Is Apache caching what's in the folders or something?

Can someone tell me what's going on?

[edit: updated for clarity]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My immediate idea is that some Apache process changed directory to `/var/www` (which you moved) or has a file in it open.  The semantics of POSIX filesystems (contrary to, say, Windows) is that it's okay to move or even delete a file or a directory from under the feet of a process which had that object open but then you might expect all kinds of funny behaviour when that process tries to access that object *by name.*

As an example, try this:

1. Run a shell (`bash` or whatever) on one console (a terminal emulator window, `screen`/`tmux` pane/window or whatever) and do this:

   ```
   $ mkdir /tmp/foo
   $ cd foo
   ```
2. Run another shell and do

   ```
   $ rmdir /tmp/foo
   ```

   in it.
3. Now go to the first shell and do

   ```
   $ pwd
   ```

   ...to get `/tmp/foo` printed.  As you can see,

   - The first shell has that directory open and runs unsuspecting.
   - The `pwd` command works just okay (because it does not reach for the filesystem).
4. Now go to the second shell and recreate the deleted directory with its original name:

   ```
   $ mkdir /tmp/foo
   ```

   Now it looks like everything's okay, right? Wrong.
5. Return back to the first shell and try to use this new directory by creating a file in it:

   ```
   $ touch blarb
   touch: cannot touch `blarb': No such file or directory
   ```

   As you can see, we're seemingly in the `/tmp/foo` directory but can't create a file in it.

   We can even get more fun by trying to recreate `/tmp/foo`:

   ```
   $ mkdir /tmp/foo
   mkdir: cannot create directory `/tmp/foo': File exists
   ```

   ...which fails because we've created that directory in the second shell.
6. Now let's "fix" the problem for the first shell:

   ```
   $ cd /tmp/foo
   $ touch blarb
   $ ls
   blarb
   ```

   As you can see, the first shell is now "in sync" with the actual world.

What to make out of this?  You're doing it wrong.  Either do not pull the rug under the feet of the web server or restart it (may be mere reloading using `service apache2 reload` would do the trick).  Note that reloading appears to be a sensible solution in either case.

Note that if you'll think about this a bit more, you'll found that the whole idea kind of stinks: for the whole duration of the operation which starts with `mv` and ends with the last `chmod` your site is malfunctioning by definition.  So it would be much better if you would do something like this:

1. `svn export` to a separate directory.  Set up permissions.
2. Bring the web server down or—better—disable the site's vhost.
3. Do two `mv`s to put your new site in place.
4. Start the webserver or bring the vhost back.

Comment: Thank you for that. That explains a lot.
edit; Does this mean, that this could theoretically happen everytime a  file or folder is replaced?

Comment: @Coo, I'd say that you *should not* rely on *any particular* behaviour of a web server.  Note that if the site is dynamic (`CGI` or whatnot) the thing becomes even more complicated as even if the webserver itself does not have any file/directory open at the time you change it, `PHP` (or whatever you're using) might, or its hosting process, if any.